# Can ArcGIS layer be shown on Google Earth?

Tags: arcgis-server, kml, google-earth

If we have a table in SQL Server which was used as layer in ArcGIS. Can the same thing be done in Google Earth?

I mean does Google Earth support adding custom layers? If so how?

Answer (score 6):

You can enable the KML/KMZ capability of an ArcGIS Server map service for rendering in Google Earth.

Answer (score 2):

Google Earth supports adding following kinds of layers - `KML, KMZ, ETA, INI`, standard image formats, various GPS receiver file formats like `GPX, PCX`, COLLADA model file in `dae` format. You could use the `File > Open` option to add layers in these formats. In order to convert your layers to these formats you could use utilities in ArcGIS or Quantum GIS.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server To KML

> "create KML documents from SQL Server
>   2008 geography data type instance"

http://sqlservertokml.codeplex.com/